# Automate Git crosslinking issues

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to somehow automate Git crosslinking feature, but I don't know if it is even possible to do as I have visioned it...

Let's say I have 2 projects - Project_A, Project_B (they are in one group)

Project_A have multiple files - File_A, File_B, File_C, ...
However Project_B don't have any files, but there are Issues with titles corresponding to file names.

For example I have file with name File_A and when there are changes in this file when I do commit or merge then these changes are referenced in Project_B issue with same name as the file: File_A

I know it's possible to make this reference with `git commit -m "this is my commit message. Ref projectname#xxx"` however you need to refer it manually, that is you have to write every singe file reference in commit AND you have to know issue ID for every corresponding.

So my main questions are:

1. Is it possible to make refenced commits automatically without writing it in commit message manually?
2. Is it possible to make refence in commits without issue ID but title instead?

I've tried using `"commit message. Ref projectname#1 Ref projectname#2"` and `"GL-xxx: commit message"`. It is possible to make multiple references in one commit message but it's quite bothersome to reference every commit if you have a lot of files with changes...

Comment: “I want to somehow automate Git crosslinking feature”—What feature is that? Is there something in Git which one can use to assist in this? Nothing comes to my mind.